# Modify div color as a function of the pageYOffset with pure CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible? Currently I'm using JS for the job, with a simple linear interpolation function which takes a color range and a scrolling domain, like so:

```
function interpolation(range, domain) {
    return function(value) {
        return range[0] + (range[1] - range[0]) * ((value - domain[0]) / (domain[1] - domain[0]));
    }
}
```

I just then pass the `pageYOffset` to the returned function and get an intermediate color, which I then apply to a div in every scroll event.

However, I would really like to be able to change the color and the alpha of a couple of divs, **gradually**, without using JS. I've seen many instances of people asking to change the color on a certain threshold and then applying a CSS transition, but that isn't what I want.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I do not believe that's possible, no.